# Language change to english in osmc

Tags: osmc

Installed osm and started in raspnerry. While playing accidently changed my osmc language setup to Welsh. Now i want to change it back to English.

Can any one help so that  i can go to the screen to change the language to english,  appreciate any help!! please share the screenshots of changing laguage setup so that i can follow.

Comment: probably easier to edit the config file - assuming you can SSH or have samba set up

Comment: Thanks , somehow i reached the correct place and able to set it back to English, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Can I suggest you post an answer - next person may not be so lucky :p